# $f$ differentiable implies remainder differentiable at zero

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, solution-verification

**Definition:** A function $f: U\subset \mathbb{R}^{m} \to \mathbb{R}^{n}$ ($U$ open) is said to be differentiable at $x_{0} \in U$ if there exists a linear map $T: \mathbb{R}^{m}\to \mathbb{R}^{n}$ such that:
$$f(x+h) = f(x) + T(h) +r(h)$$
where $\lim_{h\to 0} r(h)/|h| = 0$. Here, $r$ is called the remainder. The above equality holds provided $x+h \in U$.

For convenience, let us write $T = f'(x_{0})$ if $f$ is differentiable at $x_{0}$.

**Problem:** Suppose $f$ is differentiable at $x_{0}$ and let $B_{\delta}(x_{0})$ be an open ball with center $x_{0}$ and radius $\delta > 0$. Define $r: B_{\delta}(x_{0}) \to \mathbb{R}^{n}$ by:
$$r(h) = f(x_{0}+h)-f(x_{0}) - f'(x_{0})(h)$$
Prove that $r$ is differentiable at zero.

**My proof:** Because $r(0) = 0$, it is enough to prove that there exists a linear map $T: \mathbb{R}^{m}\to \mathbb{R}^{n}$ such that:
\begin{eqnarray}
r(h') = T(h') + \tilde{r}(h') \tag{1}\label{1}
\end{eqnarray}
holds, where $\lim_{h'\to 0}\tilde{r}(h')/|h'| = 0$. Now, let us define:
$$\rho(h') := \frac{f(x_{0}+h')-f(x_{0})-f'(x_{0})(h')}{|h'|} $$
Then, because $f$ is differentiable at $x_{0}$, we must have $\lim_{h'\to 0}\rho(h') = 0$. Thus, let $\tilde{r}(h') = |h'|\rho(h')$ and $T \equiv 0$ be the identically zero linear transformation. Then $r(h')$ can obviously satisfies (\ref{1}), and this proves the claim.

**Question:** Is my proof correct?

Answer (score 1):

I see nothing wrong with your proof but you could simplify it. In this case you could simply write:
$$r(h) = f(x_0 +h) - f(x_0)-f'(x_0)h$$ and note by the definition of derivative for $f(x)$ that,
$$\lim_{|h|\to 0} \frac{r(h)}{|h|} = 0$$ which, as $r(0)=0$, is precisely the definition of the derivative of $r(h)$ at $h=0$.

Another way that should work is $f(x)$ differentiable at $x=x_0$ implies that $g(h):= f(x_0 +h)$ is differentiable at $h=0$ and thus $r(h)$ defined above is the sum of differentiable functions, making it differentiable.